# Is it possible to compare Session::get('key') value and compare it using laravel inline if else statement?

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-6

what I'm trying to do is a filter radio button. When a user apply the filter based on a specific year, it goes into the controller to filter data results based on that year and return back to the view with new values. However when the page refreshes, the value filtered by the year **is reflected**, just that the radio button is unchecked and the default ***All*** radio button is checked.

What I did was store the radio button's id in a Session at the controller based on value of which radio button has been clicked. If the id of the radio button matches the id stored in the session, it should checked that radio button.

Index.blade.php

```
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="year" id="tab" value="_all" class="flat-red filter" checked="checked"> All
</label>

@foreach ($years as $year)
  <label>
      <input type="radio" name="year" id="id{{$year->year}}" value="{{ $year->year }}" class="flat-red filter" checked = {{ Session::get('radio') == "id{{$year->year}}" ? 'checked' : 'false' }}> {{$year->year}}
  </label>
@endforeach

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right">Apply Filter</button>
```

StatisticsController.php

```
session(['radio' => 'id'.request('year')]);
return view('statistics.index', $counts, compact('years'));
```

Error that I am getting

```
syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting :: (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM)
```

Method(s) I have tried,
1. Using JS to see which radio button has been click and store it in the local session.

What am I doing wrong or missed out?

Comment: Which line is throwing that error? What have you tried to debug this problem?

Comment: <input type="radio" name="year" id="id{{$year->year}}" value="{{ $year->year }}" class="flat-red filter" checked = {{ Session::get('radio') == "id{{$year->year}}" ? 'checked' : 'false' }}> {{$year->year}} It is coming from this line of code

Comment: Have you tried like this for comparing ? `checked = {{ session('radio') == "id".$year->year ? 'checked' : 'false' }}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything inside of `{{ }}` is PHP. The `{{ }}` gets replaced by the Blade Compiler with something like this:

```
<?php echo e(...); ?>
```

So basically just use regular PHP syntax between `{{ }}`:

```
{{ Session::get('radio') == "id{$year->year}" ? 'checked' : 'false' }}
```

Having `{{ }}` inside of `{{ }}` is going to break the compiling of that echo statement.

Comment: Yes thank you! I change the code to `<input type="radio" name="year" id="id{{$year->year}}" value="{{ $year->year }}" class="flat-red filter" {{ Session::get('radio') == "id{$year->year}" ? 'checked' : ' ' }}>` Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be to read that session variable in your controller and inject it into your template.

Don't put more logic into the template, that's not what a template engine is made for - better decouple such logic. This helps you to keep your code maintainable. A blade template does not need to know anything about a session